# mb_convert_encoding, undefined function while mbstring is enabled

Tags: php, multibyte-functions

I have a server (Ubuntu 11.10 x64) running PHP 5.3.8 with Apache2 / MySQL. I'm currently working on a project where I'm required to do some specific character encoding, but I found out that none of the multibyte (mb_* functions) are working.

However, when I look in phpinfo(), I see that multibyte support is enabled.

I've tried things like apt-get install php5-mbstring, php-mbstring, php-multibyte, etc. etc. but none seem to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? Thanks in advance!

## edit: Fixed it by recompiling PHP (this was my last resort, which I initially wanted to avoid)

./configure --enable-mbstring

The weird this is, phpinfo() already showed that it was enabled. I don't know why it didn't work before :/

Comment: what is the error message when you try any of the mb_* functions?

Comment: Web server configuration vs. CLI configuration? Where exactly do you see what?

Comment: Do you have libmbfl installed? If so - it should be shown in `phpinfo()` output as "Multibyte string engine" under mbstring.

Comment: Yeah I have that installed. However, I just noticed that the "Zend Multibyte Support" is disabled. Is there a way to enable this without having to recompile PHP?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the mbstring extension.

Comment: @EmirAkaydın - call to undefined function mb_substr or mb_convert_encoding.

Comment: now delete your question and get the Disciplined badge ;)

Comment: You solved my problem with your solution, so thanks a lot for that! :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A lot of newer Linux servers do not have PHP Multibyte modules installed by default.  A simple solution is often to install php-mbstring.

On Red Hat flavors (CentOS, Fedora, etc.) you can use yum install php-mbstring.

Make sure you restart your Apache server afterwards.   Use service httpd restart on RH flavors.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring` and then `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had additionally edit the /etc/php/7.0/mods_available/mbstring.ini and remove the ; for the extension line. Suddently it started working for me :)

Comment: After installation need to run
sudo service apache2 restart.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of your installation is php5.6 is similar to solution of neilsimp1:

Running `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring` and then `sudo service php7.0-fpm` restart did the trick for me.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
```

and then restart apache service

```
sudo service apache2 restart.
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes people receiving this kind of error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in /public_html/this/this.php at line 188. Normally this kind of errors comes in PHP Sites and PHP framework aswell.

It looks like PHP mbstring not installed on your server.

Solution :

In my case I have just uncomment ;extension=php_mbstring.dll in php.ini file and issue has been resolved.

Don't forget to restart apache server after uncomment ;extension=php_mbstring.dll

Code taken from this blog: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/01/call-to-undefined-function.html

Comment: This was the working solution for me (using windows, IIS, php 7.4). Don't forget to restart IIS.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check if MBString is Installed

You can know if it is actually installed or not with the [`-m` (Show compiled in modules) arg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)...

```
php -m | grep mbstring
```

If installed, you will see `mbstring` as the output from the above, or blank if it is not installed.

#### Install MBString

If you have the newest PHP (*PHP8* right now), you can install with...

```
apt-get install php-mbstring 
yum install php-mbstring
```

If you have *PHP7*, and you need an older MBString, then install with...

```
apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
yum install php7.0-mbstring
```

#### Restart the Server

Restart the server after install with this at your command line:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Refer back to step 1 to check that MBString actually installed.

Comment: This is very system specific, and not very widely applicable; where does php70w-mbstring come from? Most people do not run PHP as an Apache module any longer, and if they do there's a good chance the old sysv init scripts aren't available; most systems use systemd now.

Comment: Oops, that was actually a copy/paste error, thanks for catching, I meant to have [`php7.0-mbstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35892829/2430549) there.