# Cannot Initialize mbstring with PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

Whenever I try to access phpMyAdmin, I receive the following error:

**"*The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.*"**

I am running a LEMP stack on a CentOS 7 server. I have elected to use PHP 7 for this installation. I have not experienced this error on identical set-ups running earlier versions of PHP.

`extension_loaded('mbstring')` returns false even though *mbstring.ini* (/etc/php.d/) contains:

```
; Enable mbstring extension module
extension=mbstring.so
```

I am 100% sure that the mbstring module is installed on my server.

I'm completely stumped so if anyone has any ideas whatsoever, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `phpinfo();` ?

Comment: @Andrea Yep, it follows the theme with no mention of _mbstring_ at all.

Comment: in that case, mbstring isn't installed and working. `extension=` shouldn't go in `mbstring.ini` btw, I think it should go in `php.ini`

Comment: Not with PHP 7, no. From php.ini: `Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.` @Andrea

Comment: I had this problem on DigitalOcean with PHP8.  Solved with the top-answer.  I think this is a version-independent solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution was reached with the following method:

I put `extension=mbstring.so` inside php.ini even though that is no longer the method PHP uses by default to load modules.

From php.ini itself:

> Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.

It seemed to fix my problem. I would still be interested to hear if anyone else has a different take on this matter.

Comment: Perhaps the distribution of PHP 7 you used does not use the same configuration locations?

Comment: I had already installed `php7.0-mbstring` but for some reason `phpenmod mbstring` did not enable it. I had to manually enable it using this method. Additionally, my environment required a `sudo service apache2 restart` for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 86):

For those who have debian :

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

Otherwise in centos (tested in centos 6.6)

```
sudo yum install php70w-mbstring
```

and as  @mpen said you can activate it

```
sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

Comment: PS: It can be enabled with `sudo phpenmod mbstring`

Comment: I needed to restart apache too `service httpd restart`

Comment: For CentOS 7 + PHP 7, the package name was `php70u-mbstring`. If you get `No package php70w-mbstring available`, you have to do `sudo yum list | grep "\-mbstring"` to find the corresponding package.

Comment: `yum install php70-mbstring` did it for me on an Amazon Linux Instance

Comment: I just installed php7 and had the same issue. Much appreciated, Chopchop!

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft you should post your comment as an answer it solved my problem with php 5.6

Answer (score 2):

For PHP7 on centos

try this `yum install php70-mbstring`

Comment: This is the correct answer if you have php 7.0  Note, first do a php -v to find your version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time.
I found the correct way (for me) to correct it... and it's fairly simple :)

Juste add "universe" on the xenial-updates

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main **universe**
```

Answer (score -1):

run sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade before installing with sudo apt-get install php-mbstring.

I had the same problem today and found this way.