# PHP string with unicode character (\u2022) won't echo as bullet

Tags: php, json, string, unicode, encoding

I have a string which contains bullets • in  the following format:

```
$string = "Yay bullets!!\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n#somany";
```

I need to echo the string displaying the bullets. The closest I've come to printing this out is by making `$string = "\u2022";` and then echoing `json_decode('"' . $string . '"');` which prints the bullet just fine.

When I try to do the same to the full `$string` I get no result at all and no error.

Here are some things I have tried with their resulting output:

```
$raw = htmlspecialchars("Yay bullets!!\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n#yes", ENT_QUOTES);

echo $raw;
```

Result:

```
Yay bullets!!
\u2022
\u2022
\u2022
\u2022
\u2022
#yes
```

When I try:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($raw, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Result: Same as above. No change.

When I try:

```
echo json_decode('"' . $raw . '"');
```

Result: **No output.**

When I try:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($raw, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
```

Result: 奡礠扵汬整猡ℊ屵㈰㈲ੜ甲〲㈊屵㈰㈲ੜ甲〲㈊屵㈰㈲ਣ祥

I would really appreciate help figuring out how to output this properly.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

In addition to bullets, I am also failing to print emoji reference codes such as `\\ud83d\\udc93`. Reference here: http://emojipedia.org/face-with-tears-of-joy/

Comment: If you just display it on html, why not use html_entities code instead: `&#8226;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34404876/4248328  (i think this is perfect-one,but i am not sure in your case)

Comment: @AlivetoDie echoing `echo "\u$raw";` results in the same as the first two examples.

Comment: @HuyTrịnh when I do `echo htmlentities($raw);` I get the same results as the first two examples. I am echoing in console. Not in an HTML page.

Comment: @eht  check once my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this. It working for both. please check

```
 function decodeEmoticons($src) {
    $replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,4})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-16", "HTML-ENTITIES");
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'utf-16');
    return $result;
}
$r = "Yay bullets!!\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n\\u2022\n#somany";
echo decodeEmoticons($r);
$src = "\u263a\ud83d\ude00\ud83d\ude01\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude03";
echo decodeEmoticons($src);
```

Comment: code will only work if platform have mbstring installed:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728019/4248328

Comment: This works great for the bullet example. But fails when trying to convert unicode emoji like this `\\ud83d\\udc93` as it outputs ��. This is the emoji reference http://emojipedia.org/beating-heart/