# PHP decode characters with percent signs from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, character, decode, emoji

I have a `MySQL` database with a table of `latin1_swedish_ci` collation that has a `text` field which contains text such as `%u013A`,`Ok%20bro` and `%uD83D%uDE02%uD83D%uDE02`. I understand that these data contains special characters such as spaces and emojis. How can properly display these texts in `PHP`? I have tried with the numerous `PHP` functions such as `url_decode()` and `utf8_encode()` to no avail. Please help.

Edit: The table is being populated from a `node js` server that applies the function `escape()` before inserting to the table. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert latin1\_swedish\_ci data into utf8\_general\_ci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756877/how-to-convert-latin1-swedish-ci-data-into-utf8-general-ci)

Comment: @MertDalbudak Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognize `%20` as a space using in URL queries. You would need [rawurldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) to decode that.

I did find [an answer to decode the other characters here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941232/php-string-with-unicode-character-u2022-wont-echo-as-bullet?answertab=active#tab-top) and with a bit of extra code I managed to decode yours:

```
function decodeEmoticons($src) {
    $replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,4})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-16", "HTML-ENTITIES");
    $result = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'utf-16');
    return $result;
}
$r = "%uD83D%uDE02%uD83D%uDE02";
echo decodeEmoticons(str_replace('%','\\',strtolower($r)));
```

This returns "".

So perhaps you need two decodings? First the `rawurldecode()` followed by the code above. Some experimenting is needed, which I cannot do because you didn't give a lot of text to work with.

The best way to go about this is to find out how the text was encoded.

Comment: This works! A visual inspection of applying `rawurldecode()` followed by `decodeEmoticons()` seems fine on all records of the table. From what I understand, the table is being populated from a `node js` server that applies the function `escape()` before inserting to the table. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: In that case the best thing to use would be the [querystring.unescape(str)](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_unescape_str) from Node JS, but I can understand that this is not possible. Using something else always runs the risk of not always decoding it correctly.